# How to make a tumblr theme (specifically corner images) adjust to different screen resolutions?

Tags: html, css

I have a pleasant theme on tumblr ( mostlylagomorph.tumblr.com ) for a character "ask" blog.
However, even though the theme looks nice to me, and the images are all in place, other users are claiming that, on their smaller (width-wise, I presume) monitors, the characters and speech bubbles are overlapping the main content box, like so:

[[link]](https://40.media.tumblr.com/62e86d8e18769a9df272b6a7fd55729d/tumblr_npk5iyMQ4B1urfi12o2_540.png)

Also, it's worth noting that the main content box is zoomed in upon- which makes me think that the entire theme simply zooms in upon itself when subjected to a smaller screen resolution/size.

Is there any way that I can fix this issue- and make the tumblr theme adjust to different screens so that images will not overlap? Thank you so much for reading, and for your time!

This is the code that I am using for my images:

```
<img style=”position: fixed; left: 0; bottom: 0;” src=”imageurl”>
```

I can paste any other codes necessary, if it will help find a solution. Thank you!

edit: Here is the entirety of the code (erased a previous link in order to add this one- as a new user, I'm only able to add two. )

[pastebin code](http://pastebin.com/ybMBRHQi)

Comment: You are talking about responsive design. For responsive design, you need the position,dimension values in % rather than px. Please share your code it will be easier for you to get solution/suggestions.

Comment: Thank you- I'm definitely no genius when it comes to this stuff, so I appreciate all the help I can get. Here is the entirety of the code (I also changed the image code to something more manageable- found under the body tag. [link](http://pastebin.com/ybMBRHQi)

Comment: Added both codes- thank you for taking a look. I can only hope the solution will be relatively simple.

Comment: Take a look at the solution below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**CSS:**

```
.container {
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    height:auto;
}
.container img.one {
    max-width:100%;
    width:90%;
}
.container .two {
    position:absolute;
    top:0%;
    left:20%;
    width:26%
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <img class="one" src="http://orig07.deviantart.net/0543/f/2015/144/0/4/tryit_by_wdisneyrp_billcipher-d8unbap.png" />
    <img class="two" src="http://orig08.deviantart.net/dfe9/f/2015/145/8/2/office_by_wdisneyrp_billcipher-d8up8z2.png" />
</div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/732/
You can adjust width,top,left values according to your design. This is just to show you the direction to proceed.

**Tip:** Don't use jpg images in this case. Try a png with transparent background.

Comment: Wow, that was quick! Do I simply paste this under the body tag? ( and, if you don't mind me asking, how would I maneuver the images around the page, say, in different corners? )

Comment: Yes, that's it. Don't forget to copy the CSS too.

Comment: For maneuvering the images, say for top left corner, use top:0;left:0 for image. For bottom left corner: left:0;bottom:0; For top  right corner: top:0;right:0; For bottom right: right:0;bottom:0

Comment: (these questions will probably come across as silly, but i'm a bit new to this sort of thing) Lastly, where in the code should I paste the CSS? And do I paste the "left:0;bottom:0;" in the HTML (if so, where?) as well as the CSS, or only in the CSS? Thank you- you've been a huge help.

Comment: Have a look at this link:http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/734/ . It will clear your doubts.

Comment: Alright- I think I understand. The HTML pasted in with no problems whatsoever. But when I paste in the CSS, the entire theme goes bonkers. [link](http://orig00.deviantart.net/ed5a/f/2015/157/3/6/fixing__by_wdisneyrp_billcipher-d8wbp5f.png) Perhaps I messed up the code or pasted it in the wrong place along the way? I'm not too sure what triggered the reaction.

Comment: Yes, you missed a closing brace in the last part of CSS. Do one thing. Remove all the css and paste the css which I provided. Then you can add your css step by step.

Comment: The css is correct this time. I didn't understand what you meant by location. If you want the complete group of images to be positioned on different corner of page, the you will have to change the position of container itself.

Comment: Yes, exactly like that. Thank you! Can I simply input that code into the theme?

Comment: Yes, you can.. remove other css

Comment: It looks perfect, thank you! The images shrink when the screen size changes, which completely solves the problem. There is an odd sidebar on the bottom and right sides of the page that only moves the images, however, but that doesn't cause much of a problem. I'll go ahead and mark it as an answer. Thanks again for your patience!