# responsive design image scaling (tumblr theme)

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, tumblr

Apologies for a probably simple question. I have so far been getting through HTML and CSS pretty much intuitively and googling as I need to but I have reached a point of confusion.

I am trying to edit my theme so that the image of the actress overlaps the sidebar [like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTykk.png). I'd like the image to scale with the rest of the blog when zooming in/out and remain on top of the sidebar in different resolutions.

I have been trying to replicate the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30690221/how-to-make-a-tumblr-theme-specifically-corner-images-adjust-to-different-scre) to acheive this but I'm still having problems actually getting it to scale with the sidebar. It also does not overlap the sidebar (the sidebar covers it).

My edited theme so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
   <title>{Title}</title>
   <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{Favicon}">
   <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" href="{RSS}">
   {block:Description}<meta name="description" content="{MetaDescription}"/>{/block:Description}

<!--

———————————————————————————————————————
|                                       |
|      THEME 2 BY BROOK SPACEGRLL       |
|    please do not remove credit!!!     |
|    do not use this code as a base     |
|        for your own themes!!          |
|                                       |
———————————————————————————————————————

                               -->

<meta name="image:Sidebar Image" content="" />
<meta name="image:Background Image" content="" />
<meta name="image:floaty" content="" />
<meta name="if:Repeating Background" content="0" />
<meta name="if:Solid Background" content="1" />
<meta name="color:Background" content="#ffffff" />
<meta name="color:Post Background" content="#ffffff" />
<meta name="color:Scrollbar Background" content="#ffffff" />
<meta name="color:Text" content="#000000" />
<meta name="color:Borders" content="#474747" />
<meta name="color:Link" content="#333333" />
<meta name="color:Link Hover" content="#a5a5a5" />
<meta name="color:Blockquote" content="#000000" />
<meta name="color:Scrollbar" content="#dadada" />
<meta name="color:Shadow" content="#e2e2e2" />
<meta name="color:Hover Highlight" content="#ffffcb" />
<meta name="select:Font" content="Consolas" />
<meta name="select:Font" content="Inconsolata" />
<meta name="select:Font" content="Century Gothic" />
<meta name="select:Font" content="Lucida Console" />
<meta name="select:Font" content="Trebuchet MS" />
<meta name="select:Font" content="MS Gothic" />
<meta name="select:Font" content="Calibri" />
<meta name="select:Font" content="Tahoma" />
<meta name="select:Font" content="Arial" />
<meta name="select:Font" content="Helvetica" />
<meta name="if:250px" content="0" />
<meta name="if:400px" content="0" />
<meta name="if:500px" content="1" />
<meta name="if:Sidebar Image" content="1" />
<meta name="if:Translucent Post BG" content="0" />
<meta name="if:Right Sidebar" content="0" />
<meta name="if:Tiny Cursor" content="0" />
<meta name="if:Drop Down Nav" content="1" />
<meta name="if:Shadow" content="1"/>
<meta name="if:Show Source Via" content="0" />
<meta name="text:Home Title" content="home" />
<meta name="text:Nav Title" content="navigation" />
<meta name="text:Link 1 URL" content="" />
<meta name="text:Link 1" content="" />
<meta name="text:Link 2 URL" content="" />
<meta name="text:Link 2" content="" />
<meta name="text:Link 3 URL" content="" />
<meta name="text:Link 3" content="" />
<meta name="text:Link 4 URL" content="" />
<meta name="text:Link 4" content="" />
<meta name="text:Link 5 URL" content="" />
<meta name="text:Link 5" content="" />

   <style type="text/css">

{block:ifTinyCursor} *, body, a, a:hover { cursor: url(http://www.totallylayouts.com/cursors/random/tiny_cursor.png), auto; } {/block:ifTinyCursor}

::-webkit-scrollbar { height: 10px; width: 7px; background: {color:Scrollbar Background}; }

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:vertical { background: {color:scrollbar}; }

body { font-family:{select:Font}; font-size:15px; background: {block:ifSolidBackground} {color:Background}; {/block:ifSolidBackground} {block:ifnotSolidBackground} url({image:Background Image}); {block:ifRepeatingBackground} background-repeat:repeat; background-attachment:fixed; background-position:left top;{/block:ifRepeatingBackground} {block:ifnotRepeatingBackground} no-repeat center center fixed; background-attachment:fixed; -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -o-background-size: cover; background-size: cover;{/block:ifnotRepeatingBackground} {/block:ifnotSolidBackground} color:{color:Text}; }

html, body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%
}
.container {
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
}
.container img {
    position:absolute;
}
.container img.one {
    bottom:77%;
    left:12%;
    width:14%;
}


a:link, a:active, a:visited { color: {color:Link}; text-decoration:none; }

a:hover { color:{color:Link Hover}; background:{color:Hover Highlight}; }

small { font-size:auto }

big { font-size:auto }

h1 { font-size:17px; font-family:consolas; }

h2 { font-size:14px; font-family:{select:Font} }

p { margin-top:6px; margin-bottom:6px }

blockquote { padding:0px; padding-left:10px; margin:8px; border-left:1px solid {color:blockquote} }

blockquote blockquote { padding:0px; padding-left:10px; margin:8px; border-left:2px solid {color:blockquote} }

img a { border:none; width:100%; }

{block:if250px} #sidebar { position:fixed; top:130px; {block:ifRightSidebar} right:200px; {/block:ifRightSidebar} {block:ifnotRightSidebar} left:160px {/block:ifnotRightSidebar} ; width:180px; font-family:{select:font}; font-size:11px; padding:10px; } {/block:if250px}  

{block:ifnot250px} #sidebar { position:fixed; top:130px; {block:ifRightSidebar} right:190px; {/block:ifRightSidebar} {block:ifnotRightSidebar} left:120px {/block:ifnotRightSidebar} ; width:250px; font-family:{select:font}; font-size:15px; padding:10px; } {/block:ifnot250px}

#sidebar a { color:{color:Link}; text-decoration:underline; }

#sidebar a:hover { color:{color:Link Hover}; background:none; text-decoration:none; }

#sidebar img { width:145px; height:auto; text-align:center; }

#desc { position:inline; text-align:center; border:1px solid {color:Borders}; padding:15px; background:{block:ifnotTranslucentPostBG} {color:Post Background} {/block:ifnotTranslucentPostBG} {block:ifTranslucentPostBG} rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6) {/block:ifTranslucentPostBG}; {block:ifshadow} box-shadow:5px 5px {color:shadow}; {/block:ifshadow} }

.picc { position:inline; }

#linkos { text-align:center; line-height:150%; margin-top:15px; }

{block:if250px} #stuff { background:transparent; width:292px; margin-left:{block:ifRightSidebar} 440px {/block:ifRightSidebar} {block:ifnotRightSidebar} 550px {/block:ifnotRightSidebar}; margin-top:120px; position:inline; } {/block:if250px}

{block:if400px} #stuff { background:transparent; width:442px; margin-left:{block:ifRightSidebar} 340px {/block:ifRightSidebar} {block:ifnotRightSidebar}550px {/block:ifnotRightSidebar}; margin-top:120px; position:inline; } {/block:if400px}

{block:if500px} #stuff { background:transparent; width:542px; margin-left:{block:ifRightSidebar} 300px {/block:ifRightSidebar} {block:ifnotRightSidebar}550px {/block:ifnotRightSidebar}; margin-top:120px; position:inline; } {/block:if500px}

#posts { position:inline; padding:20px; margin:70px 0px 0; background:{block:ifnotTranslucentPostBG} {color:Post Background} {/block:ifnotTranslucentPostBG} {block:ifTranslucentPostBG} rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6) {/block:ifTranslucentPostBG}; border:1px solid {color:Borders}; {block:ifshadow} box-shadow:5px 5px {color:shadow}; {/block:ifshadow} }

#posts img { position:center; }

.caption { text-align:justify; }

.caption img { max-width:370px; }

#asker { margin-top:-30px; font-style:italic; }

#quote { margin-top:-10px; }

#links { margin-top:-20px; }

#photoset img { width:10px; position:center; }

#_ { margin-top:-10px; }

#footer { margin-top:0px; padding:2px; }

.info {}
.info a { text-decoration:none; color:{color:Link}; }
.info a:hover { text-decoration:none; color:{color:Link Hover}; }

.sourcevia {}
.sourcevia a { text-decoration:none; color:{color:Link}; }
.sourcevia a:hover { text-decoration:none; color:{color:Link Hover}; }

#pagination { position:inline; padding:5px; margin-bottom:80px; margin-top:40px; font-size:15px; }

#pagination a { color:{color:text}; text-align:center; text-decoration:none; }

#pagination a:hover { color:{color:Link Hover}; }

.user_1 .label { color:{color:link}; font-weight:bold }
.user_2 .label { color:{color:text}; font-weight:italic }
.user_3 .label { color:{color:link}; font-weight:text }

#notes { color:{color:Borders}; }

.chatt { margin-top:-25px; position:inline; }

ul.chat, .chat ol, .chat li { list-style:none; margin:0px; padding:0px }

#credit { margin-left:0px; bottom:0px; padding:5px; position:fixed; text-transform:uppercase; font-size:9px; color:black; }

   </style>

</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <img class="one" src="{image:floaty}" />
</div>

{block:ifnotRightSidebar}
   <div id="sidebar">
           <div id="desc">
               {block:ifSidebarImage}<div class="picc"><center><img src="{image:Sidebar Image}"></center><br>{/block:ifSidebarImage}
           {Description}
                   {block:ifnotDropDownNav}<div id="linkos"><a href="/">{text:Home Title}</a>
                       {block:ifLink1}<a href="{text:Link 1 URL}">{text:Link 1}</a>{/block:ifLink1}
                       {block:ifLink2}<a href="{text:Link 2 URL}">{text:Link 2}</a>{/block:ifLink2}
                       {block:ifLink3}<a href="{text:Link 3 URL}">{text:Link 3}</a>{/block:ifLink3}
                       {block:ifLink4}<a href="{text:Link 4 URL}">{text:Link 4}</a>{/block:ifLink4}
                       {block:ifLink5}<a href="{text:Link 5 URL}">{text:Link 5}</a>{/block:ifLink5}
                   </div>{/block:ifnotDropDownNav}
           {block:ifDropDownNav}<br><br>
               <form name="gotolocation1" method="POST" ACTION=URI>
<select name="cherrybammenu1" style="font-family:Arial; font-size:11px; color:#000; background:#fff; width:90px" onChange="location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
<option >{text:Nav Title}</option>
                       <option value="/">home</option>
                       {block:ifLink1}<option value="{text:Link 1 URL}">{text:Link 1}</option>{/block:ifLink1}
                       {block:ifLink2}<option value="{text:Link 2 URL}">{text:Link 2}</option>{/block:ifLink2}
                       {block:ifLink3}<option value="{text:Link 3 URL}">{text:Link 3}</option>{/block:ifLink3}
                       {block:ifLink4}<option value="{text:Link 4 URL}">{text:Link 4}</option>{/block:ifLink4}
                       {block:ifLink5}<option value="{text:Link 5 URL}">{text:Link 5}</option>{/block:ifLink5}
</select>
           {/block:ifDropDownNav}
{/block:ifnotRightSidebar}
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div id="stuff">
{block:Posts}

  <div id="posts">

       {block:Text}{block:Title}<h1>{Title}</h1>{/block:Title}<div class="caption">{Body}</div>{/block:Text}

       {block:Photo}{LinkOpenTag}{block:if250px} <img src="{PhotoURL-250}"> {/block:if250px} {block:if400px} <img src="{PhotoURL-400}"> {/block:if400px} {block:if500px} <img src="{PhotoURL-500}"> {/block:if500px} {LinkCloseTag}{block:Caption}<div class="caption">{Caption}</div>{/block:Caption}{/block:Photo}

       {block:Photoset}<div id="photoset">{block:if250px}{Photoset-250}{/block:if250px}{block:if400px}{Photoset-400}{/block:if400px}{block:if500px}{Photoset-500}{/block:if500px}{block:if700px}{Photoset-700}{/block:if700px}{block:Caption}<div class="caption">{Caption}</div>{/block:Caption}</div>{/block:Photoset}

       {block:Quote}<div id="quote"><h1>"{Quote}"</h1></div>{block:Source}<br><div id="source">—{Source}</div>{/block:Source}{/block:Quote}<br>

       {block:Link}<div id="links"><h1><a href="{URL}" {Target}>{Name}</a></h1></div>{block:Description}{Description}{/block:Description}{/block:Link}

       {block:Chat}<div class="chatt">{block:Title}<h1>{Title}</h1>{/block:Title}</div>{block:Lines}{block:Label}<b>{Label}</b>{/block:Label} {Line}<br>{/block:Lines}{/block:Chat}

       {block:Audio}<div id="_">{AudioPlayerBlack}<br>
       {block:TrackName}<b>Title:</b> {TrackName}<br />{/block:TrackName}
       {block:Artist}<b>Artist:</b> {Artist}<br />{/block:Artist}
       {block:ExternalAudio}<b>Download:</b> <a href="{ExternalAudioURL}">click here</a><br />{/block:ExternalAudio}<b>Played:</b> {PlayCount} times
       <br clear="all" /></div>{block:Caption}<div class="caption">{Caption}</div>{/block:Caption}<br>{/block:Audio}<br>

       block:Video}{block:if250px}{Video-250}{/block:if250px}{block:if400px}{Video-400}{/block:if400px}{block:if500px}{Video-500}{/block:if500px}{block:Caption}<div class="caption">{Caption}</div>{/block:Caption}{/block:Video}

       {block:Answer}<div id="asker">{Asker}: {Question}</div>{Answer}
{/block:Answer}

{block:NoRebloggedFrom}
{block:RebloggedFrom}{ReblogParentName}{/block:RebloggedFrom}
{/block:NoRebloggedFrom}{block:ContentSource}<!--{SourceURL}{block:SourceLogo}<img src="{BlackLogoURL}"width="{LogoWidth}" height="{LogoHeight}" alt="{SourceTitle}" />{/block:SourceLogo}{block:NoSourceLogo}{SourceLink}{/block:NoSourceLogo} --> {/block:ContentSource}

<div id="footer">
<div id="tags">
{block:HasTags}{block:Tags} <a href="{TagURL}">#{Tag}</a>
{/block:Tags}{/block:HasTags}

<div class="info">
<a href="{Permalink}">{TimeAgo}</a>{/block:Date}
<a href="{Permalink}"> ({NoteCount}) </a>

{block:ifShowSourceVia}
<div class="sourcevia" style="float:right">
{block:RebloggedFrom}<a href="{ReblogParentURL}" title="{ReblogParentName}" >via</a><font color="{color:link}"> </font><a href="{ReblogRootURL}" title="{ReblogRootName}">©</a> {/block:RebloggedFrom}

</div>
{/block:ifShowSourceVia}
</div>
</div></div>
</div>

{/block:Posts}

{block:Pagination} <div id="pagination"> {block:PreviousPage} <a href="{PreviousPage}" >prev</a> / {/block:PreviousPage}{block:NextPage} <a href="{NextPage}" >next</a> {/block:NextPage} </div> {/block:Pagination}



{block:PermalinkPage}
{block:PostNotes}
<div id="notes">{PostNotes}</div>
{/block:PostNotes}
{/block:PermalinkPage}

</div></div>

{block:ifRightSidebar}
   <div id="sidebar">
           <div id="desc">
               {block:ifSidebarImage}<div class="picc"><center><img src="{image:Sidebar Image}"></center><br>{/block:ifSidebarImage}
           {Description}
                   {block:ifnotDropDownNav}<div id="linkos"><a href="/">{text:Home Title}</a>
                       {block:ifLink1}<a href="{text:Link 1 URL}">{text:Link 1}</a>{/block:ifLink1}
                       {block:ifLink2}<a href="{text:Link 2 URL}">{text:Link 2}</a>{/block:ifLink2}
                       {block:ifLink3}<a href="{text:Link 3 URL}">{text:Link 3}</a>{/block:ifLink3}
                       {block:ifLink4}<a href="{text:Link 4 URL}">{text:Link 4}</a>{/block:ifLink4}
                       {block:ifLink5}<a href="{text:Link 5 URL}">{text:Link 5}</a>{/block:ifLink5}
                   </div>{/block:ifnotDropDownNav}
           {block:ifDropDownNav}<br><br>
               <form name="gotolocation1" method="POST" ACTION=URI>
<select name="cherrybammenu1" style="font-family:Arial; font-size:11px; color:#000; background:#fff; width:90px" onChange="location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
<option >{text:Nav Title}</option>
                       <option value="/">home</option>
                       {block:ifLink1}<option value="{text:Link 1 URL}">{text:Link 1}</option>{/block:ifLink1}
                       {block:ifLink2}<option value="{text:Link 2 URL}">{text:Link 2}</option>{/block:ifLink2}
                       {block:ifLink3}<option value="{text:Link 3 URL}">{text:Link 3}</option>{/block:ifLink3}
                       {block:ifLink4}<option value="{text:Link 4 URL}">{text:Link 4}</option>{/block:ifLink4}
                       {block:ifLink5}<option value="{text:Link 5 URL}">{text:Link 5}</option>{/block:ifLink5}
</select>
           {/block:ifDropDownNav}
{/block:ifRightSidebar}
</div></div></div>
<div id="credit"><a href="http://spacegrll.tumblr.com">©</a></div>


</html>
```

Thanks.

Comment: It would helps if you can make a pure html/css demo using SO's snippet or jsfiddle, so people can doodle with it. What you want to do is not too difficult to do, but without demo code it's pretty hard to explain.

Comment: Not sure what you mean...I don't know quite how I'd go about that, I'm an absolute beginner and my only html experience is with tumblr themes.

Answer (score 0):

OK, done now.

```
.inner{

z-index:-110;
width:100%;
height:100%;
border: 1px solid black;
position:absolute;
left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top:168%;
    bottom:0;
    margin: auto;

    text-align:center; border:1px solid #474747; padding:15px; background:  #d4c8c8  ;  
    font-size:.5em;
 }
```

The important points here are the html nesting, the position absolute and the z-index stacking the pic on top of the div.

Keep in mind this will take a bit of an amendment with media queries to make the height adaptions perfect, but this is the best i could come up with quickly.

I could try a flexbox layout, this could be done perfectly with flexbox I think. Ideally, such stuff is done in Photoshop imo.

Link to the codepen, click on where it says click to see a small demo.

http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/dYKxgW

Comment: Thanks for your time, but this isn't what I'm trying to do. There are two seperate images involved - the background and the transparent image of the actress. I'm trying to have the transparent image overlap the sidebar like in the image I linked at every resolution.

Comment: So you want the smaller image to be nested withing the bigger one and that should be responsive? I.e. 2 different sized pics one on the other? I'll do that right now.

Comment: I think so. Sorry, not entirely fluent with the language of this stuff! Thanks for your time.

Comment: http://jelliclevarietyshow.tumblr.com/ here's the code active on the blog. Ideally the transparent image should be overlapping the sidebar, and it should follow the sidebar/be attached to it in different resolutions, if that makes sense.

Comment: Check my codepen again, I have amended it. The principle is clear now to me, just give me couple minutes to extract the images straight from that code and build it in to my codepen, but the principle is the exact same , just like the codepen is right now as i type. But ill make a one to one copy for you. I'll try my best:)

Comment: Where should I be putting the new code within the original?

Comment: Frankly, I would not use that template, it is too bloated, but i will tell you where to make the changes. Just few mins.